# GitHub not highlighting my code

Tags: github

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a correct example:

[image: Highlight from github.com/svnpenn/svnpenn.github.io/diff_blob/9e5bae122226517c8426931ab12efa4241f5db7b/images/2012/highlight.png?raw=true]

Here is the sample file in my repo:

[image: highlight_no from github.com/svnpenn/svnpenn.github.io/diff_blob/9e5bae122226517c8426931ab12efa4241f5db7b/images/2012/highlight-no.png?raw=true]

Comment: The two files have different filemode attributes. Could it be related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If file has recognized name/extension

for example `hello-world.sh` then GitHub highlights based on that extension.

### Else

GitHub will highlight based on the **shebang**, but **only** if the file has the
executable bit set, ala
`chmod 755`.